# Rotated pictures on SD card can't be displayed on my camera

Tags: windows-7, sd-card, photos

While viewing pictures on my computer directly from an SD card, I decided to rotate some of them. I then put the SD card back into the camera. However, now the camera does not show the rotated pictures. Did Windows add something to the files that prevents the camera from displaying them, and if so, what can I do to undo that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows likely made changes in the metadata in the file that the camera does not recognize.  Some cameras do not recognize pictures that have been modified in this manner because they rely on a specific structure in the metadata.  I don't believe you can easily fix this, since you can't easily reproduce the metadata structure that the file originally had, unless you perform some complicated editing (possibly at the binary/hex level).

Comment: I don't know if bumping my question to Photo SE would bring more answers?

Comment: Yes, this would be more appropriate.  Flagging for moderator to migrate.

Comment: Well, that flag was marked invalid.  Seems it would be better here...

Comment: Well, then I am going to wait for more answers. I am pretty sure there must be something that can be done.